# Referencing an NSViewController's view from within an NSWindowController's nib in Interface Builder

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, appkit

If you're using NSViewController's, each with their own XIB files, is there a way to refer to those views while inside of an NSWindowController's XIB file? I want to be able to drop a view in my NSWindowController and have Interface Builder understand that that view is actually the view it can get from the embedded NSViewController.

```
MyWindowController.xib

[Objects]
-- MyViewController (Loaded from MyViewController.xib)
-- OtherViewController (Loaded from OtherViewController.xib)

[Window]
-- View
---- My View
---- Other View
```

I want Interface Builder to know that `My View` is really the view from `MyViewController`. At the moment, I'm having to manually add those views to the window's content view in something like `windowDidLoad`.

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
  ... snip ...

  [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.myViewController.view];
  [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.otherViewController.view];

  ... Configure constraints ...
}
```

This is a simplified example, but in the larger case, there might be numerous view controllers in play, each with its own view. I'd prefer to setup their initial constraints and layout in Interface Builder but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You cannot refer views from one nib to another. You can achieve what you want if your views are created programmatically.